# How to use multiple parametrizes for multiple indirect fixtures?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a test `test_row_creation` that indirectly uses two fixtures. I tried to add two parametrizes to this test with the `indirect=True` attribute and capture the value in each fixture using `request.node.funcargs["parametrize name"]`, however I'm getting the error `KeyError: 'date'` at `moderation_date: request.node.funcargs['date']`.

```
@pytest.fixture
def mocker_search_posts(mocker):
    post = Post(
        id=1,
        title='Title',
        body='Body',
        tags=['tag A']
    )

    patch = mocker.patch('path.to.search_posts', return_value=[post])
    
    return [post, patch]


@pytest.fixture
def mocker_create_post(mocker, request):
    post = Post(
        id=0,
        title='New Post Title',
        body='Body',
        tags=request.node.funcargs['tags']
    )

    return mocker.patch('path.to.create_post', return_value=post)

@pytest.fixture
def mocker_search_comments(mocker, request):
    comment = Comment(
        id=1,
        content='Comment content',
        moderation_date: request.node.funcargs['date']
    )

    patch = mocker.patch('path.to.search_comments', return_value=[comment])
    
    return [comment, patch]
    

@pytest.mark.parametrize("tags",
                     [["tag A"], ["tag A", "tag B"]],
                     indirect=True)
@pytest.mark.parametrize("date",
                     [datetime.now(pytz.utc), datetime.now(pytz.utc) - timedelta(minutes=26)],
                     indirect=True)    
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("mocker_search_comments")
def test_row_creation(mocker_search_posts, mocker_create_post):
    post, _ = mocker_search_posts
    create_posts()

    _, kwargs = mocker_create_post.call_args_list[0]
    #a few asserts
```

What do I have to do to define the two parametrize and use them on two different fixtures?

Comment: Maybe it's just me but it's unclear what you are trying to achieve. When you set `indirect=True`, then pytest would try to call a fixture of that name, in your case `tags` and `date`... which you don't have. You should be getting an error along the lines of "In test_row_creation: function uses no fixture 'tags'". In your question you say "...and use them on two different fixtures?" But in your example you don't seem to be attempting to do that. **Did you mean that you want to use the same set of tags both in `mocker_search_posts` as well as `mocker_create_post`?**

Comment: You're right. That's exactly what I was missing. I had to change the parametrize names with the names of the fixtures. Thank you